# Prevent execution of heavy-loading and / or runaway queries in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to stop/kill queries being executed on a `postgres` database based on criteria such as:

- maximum execution time
- load (CPU and/or memory) imposed on the server?

Comment: There is an extension [pg_cgroups](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_cgroups) which allows to control this to a certain degree

Answer (score 1):

You can use statement_timeout to limit execution time:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html